# Web Site Admin Tool changes do not reflect with datatbase using DefaultMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have done hands full of project with AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. Now, I have asp.net website using DefaultMembershipProvider (Just updated from AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. I thought it is better than the old one).

I created few test accounts using ASP.Net Configuration.

[image]

Accounts are created, but I don't see any record in database. I'm wondering where those records are stored.

[image]

Here is my connection string.

```
<add name="SqlConnection" connectionString=".....;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SQL Server Profile. Then I suprisingly found out that data are stored in different tables (created by DefaultMembershipProvider automatically) than I created using aspnet_regsql.exe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `connectionStringName` property of your `membership` and `roleManager` sections points to the connection string named `"SqlConnection"`?

Comment: I found out the problem; I posted it. Thank you so much for the comment.